# Flot Chart not stacking properly

Tags: charts, flot, bar-chart, stacked-chart, stackedbarseries

I have this problem with my stacked bar chart.
It is not stacking properly.

Please refer to the bar being pointed by the red arrow.
When I try to click on the lower bar, the upper bar is selected instead.

[image: Stacked Bar Chart]

Could you please help me?

The following is my data set :

> [ { "bars" : { "barWidth" : 20000,
>           "fill" : true,
>           "lineWidth" : 0,
>           "order" : 1,
>           "show" : true
>         },
>       "data" : [ [ 50000,
>             0
>           ],
>           [ 150000,
>             0
>           ],
>           [ 250000,
>             0
>           ],
>           [ 350000,
>             0
>           ],
>           [ 450000,
>             0
>           ],
>           [ 550000,
>             0
>           ],
>           [ 650000,
>             0
>           ],
>           [ 750000,
>             0
>           ],
>           [ 850000,
>             0
>           ],
>           [ 950000,
>             0
>           ],
>           [ 1050000,
>             0
>           ],
>           [ 1150000,
>             0
>           ],
>           [ 1250000,
>             0
>           ],
>           [ 1350000,
>             0
>           ],
>           [ 1450000,
>             0
>           ],
>           [ 1550000,
>             0
>           ],
>           [ 1650000,
>             0
>           ],
>           [ 1750000,
>             0
>           ],
>           [ 1850000,
>             0
>           ],
>           [ 1950000,
>             0
>           ],
>           [ 2050000,
>             0
>           ],
>           [ 2150000,
>             0
>           ],
>           [ 2250000,
>             0
>           ],
>           [ 2350000,
>             0
>           ],
>           [ 2450000,
>             0
>           ],
>           [ 2550000,
>             0
>           ],
>           [ 2650000,
>             0
>           ],
>           [ 2750000,
>             0
>           ],
>           [ 2850000,
>             0
>           ],
>           [ 2950000,
>             0
>           ],
>           [ 3050000,
>             0
>           ],
>           [ 3150000,
>             0
>           ],
>           [ 3250000,
>             0
>           ],
>           [ 3350000,
>             0
>           ],
>           [ 3450000,
>             0
>           ],
>           [ 3550000,
>             0
>           ],
>           [ 3650000,
>             0
>           ],
>           [ 3750000,
>             0
>           ],
>           [ 3850000,
>             0
>           ],
>           [ 3950000,
>             0
>           ],
>           [ 4050000,
>             0
>           ],
>           [ 4150000,
>             0
>           ],
>           [ 4250000,
>             0
>           ],
>           [ 4350000,
>             0
>           ],
>           [ 4450000,
>             0
>           ],
>           [ 4550000,
>             0
>           ],
>           [ 4650000,
>             0
>           ],
>           [ 4750000,
>             0
>           ],
>           [ 4850000,
>             0
>           ],
>           [ 4950000,
>             0
>           ],
>           [ 5050000,
>             0
>           ],
>           [ 5150000,
>             0
>           ]
>         ],
>       "stack" : true,
>       "xaxis" : 1   },   { "bars" : { "barWidth" : 20000,
>           "fill" : true,
>           "lineWidth" : 1,
>           "order" : 2,
>           "show" : true
>         },
>       "color" : "#0066FF",
>       "data" : [ [ 50000,
>             35
>           ],
>           [ 150000,
>             41
>           ],
>           [ 250000,
>             40
>           ],
>           [ 350000,
>             45
>           ],
>           [ 450000,
>             50
>           ],
>           [ 550000,
>             55
>           ],
>           [ 650000,
>             1
>           ],
>           [ 750000,
>             2
>           ],
>           [ 850000,
>             70
>           ],
>           [ 950000,
>             4
>           ],
>           [ 1050000,
>             5
>           ],
>           [ 1150000,
>             6
>           ],
>           [ 1250000,
>             7
>           ],
>           [ 1350000,
>             8
>           ],
>           [ 1450000,
>             9
>           ],
>           [ 1550000,
>             10
>           ],
>           [ 1650000,
>             11
>           ],
>           [ 1750000,
>             12
>           ],
>           [ 1850000,
>             13
>           ],
>           [ 1950000,
>             15
>           ],
>           [ 2050000,
>             30
>           ],
>           [ 2150000,
>             29
>           ],
>           [ 2250000,
>             28
>           ],
>           [ 2350000,
>             27
>           ],
>           [ 2450000,
>             26
>           ],
>           [ 2550000,
>             24
>           ],
>           [ 2650000,
>             24
>           ],
>           [ 2750000,
>             23
>           ],
>           [ 2850000,
>             22
>           ],
>           [ 2950000,
>             21
>           ],
>           [ 3050000,
>             20
>           ],
>           [ 3150000,
>             19
>           ],
>           [ 3250000,
>             18
>           ],
>           [ 3350000,
>             17
>           ],
>           [ 3450000,
>             16
>           ]
>         ],
>       "label" : "Fruits",
>       "stack" : true,
>       "xaxis" : 1   },   { "bars" : { "barWidth" : 20000,
>           "fill" : true,
>           "lineWidth" : 1,
>           "order" : 3,
>           "show" : true
>         },
>       "color" : "#93CDDD",
>       "data" : [ [ 150000,
>             65
>           ],
>           [ 750000,
>             32
>           ]
>         ],
>       "label" : "Vegetables",
>       "stack" : true,
>       "xaxis" : 1   },   { "bars" : { "barWidth" : 20000,
>           "fill" : true,
>           "lineWidth" : 1,
>           "order" : 4,
>           "show" : true
>         },
>       "color" : "#0066FF",
>       "data" : [ [ 450000,
>             100
>           ],
>           [ 950000,
>             50
>           ],
>           [ 1450000,
>             114
>           ],
>           [ 1550000,
>             6
>           ],
>           [ 1750000,
>             44
>           ],
>           [ 1850000,
>             71
>           ],
>           [ 2550000,
>             2
>           ],
>           [ 2850000,
>             71
>           ],
>           [ 2950000,
>             35
>           ],
>           [ 3250000,
>             99
>           ]
>         ],
>       "label" : "Animals",
>       "stack" : true,
>       "xaxis" : 1   } ]

Comment: Please do not open duplicate questions.  If you'd like to add more information, edit your existing question.

Comment: Also, since this question had the better information (your data series), I flagged the other one for moderator attention and closure.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a bug in the stacking plugin.

Your "vegetables" series in between your "fruits" and "animals" series doesn't have a bar at that location (450000).  It's causing the plugin to not stack the "fruits" and "animals" series but instead overlay them.  Adding a `0` bar to the "vegetables" series at that location fixes the issue:

```
{
    "bars": {
      "barWidth": 20000,
      "fill": true,
      "lineWidth": 1,
      "order": 3,
      "show": true
    },
    "color": "green",
    "data": [
      [150000, 65],
      [450000, 0], // ADDED THIS POINT
      [750000, 32]
    ],
    "label": "Vegetables",
    "stack": true,
    "xaxis": 1
  }
```

Here's a fixed [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/2mufNcsAC1ztYc8j2YQA?p=preview).  I changed the colors to better visualize what's going on.

Comment: You're right that this is a bug it's referenced here: https://github.com/flot/flot/issues/326 There is a partial fix fork referenced near the end of that thread.
Unfortunately it seems that Flot is basically unmaintained now, which is a real shame considering that commercial equivalents start in the hundreds, if not thousands, of dollars depending on your applicaiton.